# Selecting innermost child of an element Jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am attempting to scrape the following html:

```
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellRight" style="cursor:pointer;">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="cellRight" style="border:0;color:#0066CC;"
                    title="View summary" width="70%">92%</td>

                    <td class="cellRight" style="border:0;" width="30%">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="listroweven">
        <td class="cellLeft" nowrap><span class="categorytab" onclick=
        "showAssignmentsByMPAndCourse('08/03/2015','58100:6');" title=
        "Display Assignments for Art 5 with Ms. Martinho"><span style=
        "text-decoration: underline">58100/6 - Art 5 with Ms.
        Martinho</span></span></td>

        <td class="cellLeft" nowrap>
            Martinho, Suzette<br>
            <b>Email:</b> <a href="mailto:smartinho@mtsd.us" style=
            "text-decoration:none"><img alt="" border="0" src=
            "/genesis/images/labelIcon.png" title=
            "Send e-mail to teacher"></a>
        </td>

        <td class="cellRight" onclick=
        "window.location.href = '/genesis/parents?tab1=studentdata&tab2=gradebook&tab3=coursesummary&studentid=100916&action=form&courseCode=58100&courseSection=6&mp=MP4';"
        style="cursor:pointer;">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="cellCenter"><span style=
                    "font-style:italic;color:brown;font-size: 8pt;">No
                    Grades</span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="listrowodd">
        <td class="cellLeft" nowrap><span class="categorytab" onclick=
        "showAssignmentsByMPAndCourse('08/03/2015','58200:10');" title=
        "Display Assignments for Family and Consumer Sciences 5 with Sheerin">
        <span style="text-decoration: underline">58200/10 - Family and
        Consumer Sciences 5 with Sheerin</span></span></td>

        <td class="cellLeft" nowrap>
            Sheerin, Susan<br>
            <b>Email:</b> <a href="mailto:ssheerin@mtsd.us" style=
            "text-decoration:none"><img alt="" border="0" src=
            "/genesis/images/labelIcon.png" title=
            "Send e-mail to teacher"></a>
        </td>

        <td class="cellRight" style="cursor:pointer;">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="cellCenter"><span style=
                    "font-style:italic;color:brown;font-size: 8pt;">No
                    Grades</span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to extract the values for the student's grades, and if no grades are present, the value "no grades" which will be present in the html if this is the case. However, when I do a select request such as the following:

```
doc.select("[class=cellRight]")
```

I get an output where all of the grade values are listed twice (because they are nested within two elements containing the [class=cellRight] distinguisher, and the normal amount of "no grades" listing. So my question is, how can I only select the innermost child in a document which contains the distinguisher [class=cellRight]? (I have already dealt with the issue of a blank value) All help is appreciated!!

Comment: can you clean up the html?

Comment: is that better? @luksch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possibilities to to this.

One would be this: Test for each "cellRight" element all its parents if they also carry that class. Discard if you find it:

```
List<Element> keepList = new ArrayList<>();
Elements els = doc.select(".cellRight");
for (Element el : els){
  boolean keep = true;
  for (Element parentEl : el.parents()){
     if (parentEl.hasClass("cellRight")){
        //parent has class as well -> discard!
        keep = false;
        break;
     }
  }
  if (keep){
    keepList.add(el);
  }
}
//keepList now contains inner most elements with your class
```

Note that this is written without compiler and out of my head. There might be spelling/syntax errors.

Other note. your use of `"[class=cellRight]"` works well only if there is this single class. With multiple clsses in random order (which is totally to be expected) it is better to use  the dot syntax `".cellRight"`